# jQuery keep show hide state based on select option

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have drop down select and show hide other fields (within divs) based on option selected in the dropdown list.

This code works fine and show hide based on selection but when I load the page all fields are visible.

Other thing is for instance if I want to show fields if option 2 selected and save the option to the database and when reload the page it is not saving the show hide state based on the option selected.

**HTML**

```
<select id="row1_layout_options" name="row1_layout_options">
    <option value="Select Layout Type">Select Layout Type</option>
    <option value="layout_type1">layout_type1</option>
    <option value="layout_type2">layout_type2</option>
    <option value="layout_type3">layout_type3</option>
    <option value="layout_type4">layout_type4</option>
    <option value="layout_type5">layout_type5</option>
    <option value="layout_type6">layout_type6</option>
    <option value="layout_type7">layout_type7</option>
    <option value="layout_type8">layout_type8</option>
</select>

<div id="row1_col1_layout_type2">
    <input type="text" class="qa-form-tall-text" value="" name="q2am_fp_row1_col1_layout_type2">
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#row1_layout_options').change(function() {
   $('#row1_col1_layout_type1, #row1_col1_layout_type2, #row1_col1_layout_type3').hide();
   $('#row1_col1_' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

So how can I write script where all fields are hidden on page load but it will keep show hide state based on selected option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign an common class to all the div's that holds the content

> show hide based on selection but when I load the page all fields are
>   visible

```
<div id="row1_col1_layout_type2" class="content">
                                        ^
                                        ----- This to target with a single selector
```

**CSS**

```
.content{
   display :none;
}
```

And in the **JS** just trigger the change event so as to show the div with option that is selected

```
$('#row1_layout_options').change(function() {
   $('.content').hide();
   $('#row1_col1_' + $(this).val()).show();
   // Sen d an ajax request to save the value in DB
   $.ajax({

   });
}).change();  <--- Trigger the event
```

Next is the Page Reload. Web is `stateless` . So it will not remember the previous state. The only thing you can do is persist the value after page refresh. Maybe in as a cookie, Local Storage or saving it on server and retrieving it back..
**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/HgqAn/1/)**

Comment: Okay that can be done but what about to show the field based on option selected and saved?

Comment: This will fix the issue of the elements appearing on load but not the issue of saving the selected value in the <select>.

Comment: This is not working. It is still hiding the selected option's field on page load

Comment: @pixelngrain.. There was a small typo in the HTML structure.. Check updated code and working example

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Comment: Imho, I would rather use more CSS than more JS. just sayin

Answer (score 0):

Just do the same in `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#row1_col1_layout_type1, #row1_col1_layout_type2, #row1_col1_layout_type3').hide();
    $('#row1_col1_' + $('#row1_layout_options').val()).show();

    $('#row1_layout_options').on('change',function() {
       $('#row1_col1_layout_type1, #row1_col1_layout_type2, #row1_col1_layout_type3').hide();
       $('#row1_col1_' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MsYGJ/8/)

Comment: I am sorry but this also doesn't load the fields for selected option on page load

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a class for your loaded content which will make them hidden.

**HTML**

```
<select id="row1_layout_options" name="row1_layout_options">
    <option value="Select Layout Type">Select Layout Type</option>
    <option value="layout_type1">layout_type1</option>
    <option value="layout_type2">layout_type2</option>
    <option value="layout_type3">layout_type3</option>
    <option value="layout_type4">layout_type4</option>
    <option value="layout_type5">layout_type5</option>
    <option value="layout_type6">layout_type6</option>
    <option value="layout_type7">layout_type7</option>
    <option value="layout_type8">layout_type8</option>
</select>

<div id="layouts">
    <div id="row1_col1_layout_type2">
        <input type="text" class="qa-form-tall-text" value="" name="q2am_fp_row1_col1_layout_type2">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#row1_layout_options').change(function() {
   $('#layouts>div.selected').removeClass('selected');
   $('#row1_col1_' + $(this).val()).addClass('selected');
});
```

**CSS**

```
#layouts>div{
    display:none;
}

#layouts>div.selected{
    display:block;
}
```

**EDIT : Saving selected**

As for saving the selected option you have these non exhaustive list of solution :

- **HTML5 localstorage**, you can use `localStorage` which is a javascript accessible store that is flushed like cookies. I wouldn't recommend that one I found it very much unreliable.
- **Server side persistence**. Basically when you set an option as `selected` you send a query to a webservice that will save the state somewhere (DB, object instance etc...)
- **URL modification**. that's not really a persistence solution but it could match the need sometimes. You can retrieve a value in the URL parameter section like `http://localhost/mysite?selectedId=2`. This way you can have the information directly within the link. Easier to share the state.